# Meaning of 家族ポイントを消費

Tags: meaning, idioms

What is the meaning of 家族ポイント and 家族ポイントを消費?

Examples:

> 家族ポイントを消費して行くオプションもありましたが、年の初めから無理をすることもなかろうと看病モード。
>
> かなりの家族ポイントを消費しつつ、札幌歴史ゲーム友の会の例会に久々に参加しました。
>
> 家庭にオーブン付レンジをお持ちのお父さん、絆ばかりで家族ポイントを消費がちだと思いますので、株を上げるのは如何でしょう？（黒いな）

Are 家族ポイント a kind of "points" that are earned by doing some 家族サービス and can be spent on non-family leisure? Or am I misunderstanding the concept?

I particular in the 3rd example, I fail to see why having an oven would have a negative point impact.

Answer (score 4):

(すみません、文脈を勘違いしていたので修正します)

家族ポイント is not an established idiom.

家族ポイント in these examples can be understood as "level of confidence from their family". That's something you lose when you are away from your family and absorbed in your hobby. This is a very ゲーマー臭い word play which non-gamers are unlikely to think of, and it seems that all the three authors of these sentences are core gamers.

In your third example ([original post here](http://blog.livedoor.jp/kusunoki3378/archives/52538907.html)), the cause of losing his 家族ポイント is not the oven but 絆 (=[機動戦士ガンダム 戦場の絆](http://web.gundam-kizuna.jp/sp/)). That part can be translated into plain Japanese as "戦場の絆をプレイしてばかりいるせいで、家族からの信頼を失いがちだと思いますので".